# Is there any remote desktop solution featuring hardware acceleration?

Tags: remote-desktop, gpu

I'm interested in remotely controlling my Linux desktop, that has a strong GPU, from my weaker notebooks. Since most remote-desktop software like VNC/RDP aren't hardware accelerated, the video transmission experience is awful in comparison to cloud gaming software like Parsec, Steam or Moonlight: the difference in quality and latency is ridiculous. As such, I've been using Parsec to remotely access my Windows desktop, it works blazingly fast. Sadly, it only accepts Windows as the server. It would be great if either a cloud gaming software supported Linux hosts, or if a remote desktop software featured hardware acceleration. Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use the steam link package which is part of the Steam Client. I access it through picture mode. I haven’t done enough research to know if the connection is encrypted, but it may well be. Once running you can close the picture mode and you are then in Windows/Linux desktop. It would appear they support Android and Raspberry Pi architecture for the steam link viewer app.

https://store.steampowered.com/about/
https://store.steampowered.com/steamlink/about/